# Why I can’t receive complete string from Arduino to Android using Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am sending strings from arduino to Android by bluetooth, when strings arrive to the application I make substrings in order to get the data I need. However, the strings are coming incomplete, they are cut and therefore I can’t get the substrings that I need. For example: From Arduino I send strings of this style:

`#ecg{21304(2.41~`

When I send several strings on the arduino serial monitor look like these:

```
#ecg{0(137~
#ecg{1(136~
#ecg{3(162~
#ecg{5(221~
#ecg{6(282~
#ecg{8(296~
#ecg{10(259~
#ecg{12(208~
#ecg{13(166~
#ecg{15(141~
#ecg{17(132~
#ecg{19(144~
#ecg{20(194~
#ecg{22(262~
#ecg{24(296~
#ecg{26(267~
#ecg{27(217~
#ecg{29(173~
#ecg{31(143~
```

But when they arrive to Android this arrive cut, something like this:

```
I/System.out: ReadMessage: #ecg{6147 end string
I/System.out: ReadMessage: 0(335~
I/System.out: #ecg{61472(335~
I/System.out: #ecg{61474(273~
I/System.out: #ecg{61476(230~
I/System.out: #ecg{61478(252~
I/System.out: #ecg{61480(307~
I/System.out: #ecg{61483(307~
I/System.out: #ecg{61485(279~
I/System.out: #ecg{61487(306~
I/System.out: #ecg{61488(347~
I/System.out: #ecg{61490(313~
I/System.out: #ecg{61492(249~
I/System.out: #ecg{61494(231~
I/System.out: #ecg{61496(277~
I/System.out: #ecg{61498(320~
I/System.out: #ecg{61500 end string
I/System.out: ReadMessage: (290~
I/System.out: #ecg{61502(284~
I/System.out: #ecg{61504(328~
I/System.out: #ecg{61506(343~
I/System.out: #ecg{61507(283~
I/System.out: #ecg{61509(237~
I/System.out: #ecg{61511(246~
I/System.out: #ecg{61513(303~
I/System.out: #ecg{61515(311~
I/System.out: #ecg{61517(280~
I/System.out: #ecg{61519(301~
I/System.out: #ecg{61521(346~
I/System.out: #ecg{61523(321~
I/System.out: #ecg{61524(258~
I/System.out: #ecg{61527(230~
I/System.out: #ecg{61529( end string
I/System.out: ReadMessage: 269~
I/System.out: #ecg{61531(318~
```

**Note that from the beginning they aren’t arriving complete in most cases.**

I want to get strings like these:

```
I/System.out: ReadMessage: #ecg{61502(284~ end string
I/System.out: ReadMessage: #ecg{61502(284~ end string
I/System.out: ReadMessage: #ecg{61504(328~ end string
I/System.out: ReadMessage: #ecg{61506(343~ end string
I/System.out: ReadMessage: #ecg{61507(283~ end string
```

And therefore I can’t create the substrings that I need. Do you know why the Strings are cut and not complete as I send them from the arduino? Is there any way to solve it?

Can be that the incomplete strings reception is for the speed transmission that I used in the Arduino code (115200)?
I tested loading a program on another arduino that sends data via bluetooth to the same app and these arrive well, the difference is that it send the data to 9600

This is the Arduino code that I send:

```
    #include <eHealth.h>

  String CadenaUno="";
  String CadenaDos="";
  String CadenaTres="";
  String CadenaFinal="";

// The setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  Serial.flush();
  Serial.begin(115200);
 // Serial.begin(9600); //No muestra nada en android studio a esta velocidad
}
// The loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
        long currentMillis = millis();
        float floatecgValue = eHealth.getECG();
        int valueECG = floatecgValue*100;
                    CadenaUno="#ecg{";
                    CadenaDos="(";
                    CadenaTres="~";
                    CadenaFinal=CadenaUno+currentMillis+CadenaDos+valueECG+CadenaTres;                    
                    Serial.println(CadenaFinal);    
                   delay(1); 
}
```

This is the part where I verify the data that arrives from arduino by Bluetooth

```
        while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
                String paquete = "";

                String outputText="";
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                mDataParse.Add(buffer, bytes);
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                System.out.println("ReadMessage: "+readMessage+" end string");
```

Please Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
String prev = null;
while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
    try {
        StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
        String paquete = "";

        String outputText = "";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
        mDataParse.Add(buffer, bytes);
        String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
        //Split by new line symbol
        String[] msgs = readMesage.split("\n");
        int msgsCount = msgs.length;
        //Check is we have a prev not completed message?
        if (msgsCount > 0) {
            if (prev != null)
                msgs[0] = prev + msgs[0]; //add it to first message

            //Check is last message completed?
            if (readMessage.endsWith("\n"))
                prev = null;
            else {
                prev = msgs[msgsCount - 1]; //Set last message to prev and remove it from output
                msgsCount--;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < msgsCount; i++) {
                System.out.println("ReadMessage: " + msgs[i] + " end string");
            }
        }
    }
```